# How to make the symbols look neater

Tags: symbols

When I type `$\varprojlim_n$` in the common inline math environment I get the picture as below.

[image: https://latex.artofproblemsolving.com/p/t/s/ptslxdxp.png?time=1503640057617]

However I want to be rendered as [image].

The same thing happens with summations. I understand that if I use the paragraph math mode it will solve my problem. Unfortunately, that is not an option. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `\varprojlim\limits_{n}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four styles used in typesetting math formulas which affect the size and certain formatting parameters (notably the placement of sub and superscripts on variable size symbols):

- `\textstyle`: default in the running text and in array environment
- `\displaystyle`: default for displayed equations
- `\scriptstyle:`: default for first-level sub and superscripts
- `\scriptscriptstyle`: default for higher-level sub and superscripts

Take a look at the following document to see how the appearance changes when different styles are used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

$\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$,
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$,
$\scriptstyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$,
$\scriptscriptstyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Now, coming back to your specific query, use `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

$\varprojlim_n$ $\displaystyle\varprojlim_n$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: or 999 times out of 100, it is better to use display math than inline math with `\displaystyle` so  use `\[\varprojlim_n\]`